# complex case with 3 ways

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a complex case that I would appreciate to have your advice on it.

when **Order_id** exist and if there are 2 rows with the same order_id :
**then** select the row that have no null on **seller** and **comment**
**else** select the row with **seller** and null on the **comment** and change the null to  ***comment not provided***
(change the null to not provided)

when order_id does not exist - put not found in both **seller** and **comment**

Please see the date example and the Desired result on the photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF8au.png)

```
WITH cte1 as (
SELECT 
      a.order_id,  
     ,a.cat_id,
     ,COALESCE(b.seller, 'No reason found') as seller
     ,COALESCE(b.comment, 'No comment found') as comment
 FROM table2 AS a
LEFT JOIN table1 AS b
ON a.order_id = b.order_id
and a.cat_id = b.cat_id
GROUP BY 
a.order_id
     ,a.cat_id
     ,COALESCE(b.seller, 'No reason found') 
     ,COALESCE(b.comment, 'No comment found') 
)
,
cte2 as (
select 
order_id,  
cat_id,
name,
brand,
year,

from table2 


) 

select
cb.order_id,  
cb.cat_id,
cb.name,
cb.brand,
cb.year,
ca.seller,
ca.comment
from cte1 as ca left join mca as cte2 as cb on 
ca.order_id=cb.order_id
and ca.cat_id=cb.cat_id
GROUP BY
cb.order_id,  
cb.cat_id,
cb.name,
cb.brand,
cb.year,
ca.seller,
ca.comment
```

Comment: I think your order_id and cat_id have some mismatches in both tables.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that and uploaded the right one. I would appreciate your adivce

Comment: Please post the query you've tried, along with sample data. If you want help, an image is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I have just posted it. I would appreciate your advice as I'm struggling to get the output I need

Answer (score 0):

1 of the possible way is -

```
SELECT T2.order_id,
       T2.cat_id,
       T2.name,
       T2.brand,
       T2.year,
       T1.seller,
       NVL(T1.comment, 'comment not provided')
  FROM table2 T2
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_id,
                    cat_id,
                    NVL(T1.seller, 'NOT FOUND'),
                    NVL(COLLECT_SET(comment), 'NOT FOUND') comment
               FROM table1
              GROUP BY order_id, cat_id, seller) T1 ON T1.order_id = T2.order_id
                                                    AND T1.cat_id = T2.cat_id;
```

Though I have not tried the query yet, But I think It should work.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to run it  on HIve and get this error:      Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:342 missing ) at 'WITHIN' near 'WITHIN' in subquery source line 1:349 mismatched input '(' expecting ) near 'WITHIN' in subquery source

Comment: I have been never used it in 'WITHIN GROUP', is there something to use instead?

Comment: @Matias021, Try the query now.

Comment: Thanks, this is the error I'm getting now (Never seen something like this) : Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NullPointerException null

Comment: Is this error coming from hive or from your front-end app?

Comment: Hey, I belive is From Hive

Comment: Hey, please advice

Comment: In case the cat_id doesn't exist, how the left join will work?